# .c FIle Dedicated to Data

Tags: programming-practices, c

Is it completely unheard of to have a `.c` file dedicated to just data? In my case, I'd be using it for global variables that are shared across two other `.c` files. Here's specifically how I'm using it.

```
// serverth.h

struct serverth_parameters {
    struct { // right now, this is the only struct needed
        char * root,
             * user,
             * public,
             * site;
    } paths;

    // I anticipate needing another struct here

};

#ifndef SERVERTH_SOURCE
extern struct serverth_parameters parameters;
#endif
```

---

```
// serverth.c

#define SERVERTH_SOURCE
#include "serverth.h"

struct serverth_parameters parameters = {
    .paths = { // macros are actually used here
        "/srv",
        "/user",
        "/public"
        "/site"
    }
};
```

---

`parameters` is a struct that's used for a websockets server, in two files:

- One for HTTP (uses `parameters.paths.site`)
- Two for proprietary protocols (both use `.paths.user`, one uses `paths.public`)

Is this a bad practice? Do people do this? Or, is it more conventional to just keep the data in the source file in which it is most relevant?

Comment: It's not unheard of, but I'm scared that you feel like you need such a file and that you'd think you need to put more globals in there.

Comment: okay, I'll explain the context a little more

Comment: sounds acceptable, as long as these "global variables" you originally mentioned can be defined as constants as we see them here.

Comment: okay. can you post that as an answer?

Comment: Comment on style - "#ifndef SERVERTH_SOURCE" - why are you doing this? By doing this you are removing a valuable safety guard - consider it very bad practice.

Comment: I thought that I should, so it wouldn't be `extern` in the file that declares it. Does that matteR?

Comment: @TaylorFlores: No, it does not matter. The presence of the initializer on the second declaration (in the .c file) is sufficient to make the compiler understand you mean to define the variable and not merely declare it.

Comment: okay, I've already taken it out. I'm not sure how I started thinking that in the first place

Comment: Your example sounds like you want a configuration file.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Yeah, I'll probably do that last though.

Comment: Pre-computed tables/matrices/encodings may serve as reasonable candidates for data as source files.  Device IO maps are another take on that same idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general I'd be wary of "dumping ground" files, where one would start listing global variables or long lists of `#define`s.

However, if by "globals" you actually meant that these globals would be constants, then that would seem acceptable, as long as they are structured and re-grouped in meaningful patterns, and that the extent of their reuse justifies to extract them to a separate file.

If these conditions aren't satisfied, then I'd usually restrain them to the file where they're expected to be used, if possible.

#### [Include Guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)

On a different note, I don't know how your files are compiled and what build system you use, but you might want to use compilation guards of the form:

```
#ifndef MY_MODULE
# define MY_MODULE

/* stuff here */

#endif
```

Comment: I'm using cmake. you're talking about the header file right?

Comment: @TaylorFlores: yes, sorry if that was confusing.

Comment: *Include* guards should not start with underscores (and once you get rid of those, the trailing underscores look silly). Names starting with double underscores, or a single underscore and a capital letter, are reserved for the implementation. Just use `#ifndef MY_MODULE` or `MY_MODULE_H`

Comment: @delnan: `guards should not start with underscores` that's just, lile, you know, your preference (and convention), man :) It's not the most adopted convention, but who cares. Works all the same. I agree on the missing `_H` though, I had forgotten that, but usually I used names with it indeed.

Comment: No, there is one hard fact in favor of not starting them with underscores (as I mentioned before): Such names are reserved by the standards; a compiler, run time library, standard library module, etc. may use that name. Consider that the collision may only occur in a particular version of a particular tool chain which you don't test your code with but which is used to build your code a year later. It's indeed "just a convention", but an overwhelmingly superior one.

Comment: @delnan: I just checked the standard and you are right. I thought only the C++ standard mandated that, but the ISO/IEC 9899 mandes it as well. I stand corrected. Thanks.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: you -1 on something that has nothing to do with the question, though. But anyways, as I just wrote back to delnan, I stand corrected and will amend my answer.

Comment: @haylem: I have reverted my downvote (and turned it into an upvote). The fact that it was based on a part of the answer that does not directly relate to the question is not a reason for me to condone bad advise. I have deleted my previous comment to avoid confusion with future readers.